# how to access a parameter with a # in a bash script

Tags: bash

I have a script to slugify a series of words and characters.  Thing is, when a script parameter uses a # the rest of the line after the # is not passed to my script.  How can you access the arguments after and including the # symbol?

Example:

```
$ make_slug this is a very long line #450
```

Returns:

```
this-is-a-very-long-line
```

The script parameters from # are dropped as they are being passed into the scrip code.  Sample code:

```
arguments=""
for arg in "$@"
do
    echo "$arg"
    cleaned=`echo $arg | sed -e 's/[^0-9A-Za-z]//g' -e '/./!d'`
    arguments+=${cleaned,,}"-"
done
echo ${arguments::-1}
```

Comment: Can you give a specific example, in context? Generally, you can *escape* such special characters with a backslash e.g. `\#parameter` or use appropriate quotes e.g. `"#parameter"`

Answer (score 0):

I probably did not understand your question, here I am assuming that you have a file/variable containing lines of text in each of which you want to remove all text from the symbol `#` to the end of the line.

If this is the case, and assuming that you don't want this behaviour for escaped occurrences `\#`, this is how I would do:

```
sed 's/\([^\\]\)#.*$/\1/g' filename
```

if the text is contained in the file `filename`, or, if it is contained in the variable `var`,

```
sed 's/\([^\\]\)#.*$/\1/g' <<< "$variable"
```

### Example

Suppose your file `filename` contains the following text

```
This is a line#this is a comment
this is another line without comments
this is a line with an escaped sharp symbol \# and therefore this is NOT a comment
```

then the above command yields

```
This is a line
this is another line without comments
this is a line with an escaped sharp symbol \# and therefore this is NOT a comment
```

### Explanation

```
sed 's/\([^\\]\)#.*$/\1/g'
```

- `sed` is a **s**tring **ed**itor: `'s/matched-pattern/replaced-pattern/options'`. `s` stands for **s**ubstitution, and the option `g` for **g**lobal, i.e. it does not stop after the first substitution.
- `[^\\]` mathces everything that is **not** a backslash `\` (which needs be escaped, hence the double `\\`)
- `\(pattern\)` stores the matched `pattern` and is referred to with `\1` in the replacement pattern
- `.*$` matches any character 'till the end of the line

Comment: Sorry, I needed to add more details to the question.  Have a look now.